# Use gtag.js to track virtual pageviews

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics

I have a multipage registration form and I want to track user's path through  the form using Google Tag Manager. My page uses a recommended code snippet in the header to track page view:

```
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
gtag('js', new Date());
gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXXXX');
```

According to [documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/pages) I generate a virtual page view when a user clicks a certain button in the form:

```
gtag('js', new Date());
gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXX', {
     'page_title' : 'User registration',
     'page_path': '/registration/page2'
});
```

However, this code doesn't add a new page view. It *overrides* the original one. What am I doing wrong? I want a new pageview to be generated when the user clicks a button.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like you're using GTM, but gtag.js instead.

You'll need to trigger it on click events. Something like:

```
<button onclick="formStep2()">Click me</button>
```

Then for the formStep2() function:

```
function formStep2(){
    gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXX', {
     'page_title' : 'User registration',
     'page_path': '/registration/page2'
    });
}
```

Of course, you can setup the function to be more generic/useful by passing in a parameter indicating the path/title as well.

Comment: The code is more complex, I've just posted a snippet. So yes, it is run in a onclick event of the button. What do you mean by using gtag.js and what's the difference to GTM? I thought the gtat function is defined in the initial snippet.